# SSIS, XML Sources with XSD files... and nvarchar(max) destination columns

Tags: sql-server, xml, unicode, ssis, xsd

Here is the problem:

- I've been handed an SSIS Package to update which uses an XML Source to read data from XML files and read its content into multiple tables.
- The XML Source has an XMLSchemaDefinition property that points at an external .xsd file. This .xsd file might receive updates as the related data source specification evolves.
- One of the columns in one of the destination tables is nvarchar(max).

In the XML Source's Advanced Editor > Input and Output Properties I can manually set this element's DataType properties to `Unicode text stream [DT_NTEXT]` and get the correct transformation behaviour. However, the next time somebody comes into this screen and clicks the `Refresh` button my change will be undone and things will start breaking.

When I was first given this package to work on the .xsd element had the definition:

```
<xs:attribute name="SomeLongText" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
```

This results in a DataType of `Unicode string [DT_WSTR]` and Length `255`, 255 being the default.

SSIS also responds to simpleType definitions, e.g.:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="string100">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="100" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <!-- ... -->
  <xs:attribute name="SomeLongText" type="string100" use="optional" />
```

This results in `Unicode string [DT_WSTR]` with Length `100` as expected.

Now, [Integration Services Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/integration-services-data-types) has this to say about the DT_NTEXT data type:

> DT_NTEXT  A Unicode character string with a maximum length of 2^30 - 1
>   (1,073,741,823) characters.

1,073,741,823 sounds like a good, relevant number to use here so if I define a simpleType with that restriction:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="stringMax">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="1073741823" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <!-- ... -->
  <xs:attribute name="SomeLongText" type="stringMax" use="optional" />
```

In SSIS I get the DataType of `Unicode string [DT_WSTR]` with Length `4000`, which seems to be the maximum limit of DT_WSTR.

If I leverage knowledge that `sys.columns` reports nvarchar(max) columns as having length -1 and try this instead:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="stringMax">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="-1" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <!-- ... -->
  <xs:attribute name="SomeLongText" type="stringMax" use="optional" />
```

I get the following error message in SSIS when clicking `Refresh`

> Error at Data Flow Task [XML Source [229]]: There was an error setting
>   up the mapping. The MaxLength constraining facet is invalid - Value
>   '-1' was either too large or too small for NonNegativeInteger.

I guess that rules out -1 then.

So, my question is: What magic do I need to put in the .xsd file to coax the XML Source to treat the source element as `Unicode text stream [DT_NTEXT]`?

I want this to be compatible with the `Refresh` button going forward so that the next poor schmuck having to deal with this (possibly me) doesn't break things.

Thanks and kind regards,
Ant.

Comment: One approach might be to send in a unicode string as byte array and read it as `VARBINARY(MAX)` which can be re-converted to string like `CAST(YourByteStream AS NVARCHAR(MAX))`. I think, that in this case you'd have no limit. In the very last corner of my brain there is the idea, that you could pass the whole thing as `XML` like `<p>All text</p>`. Strings are limited, XML and BLOBs aren't. But - to be honest - I have no experience with SSIS.

Comment: @Shnugo: thank you for your feedback. The particular source column is essentially a wall of text. Specifically it's human-entered evaluations of scientific data, maybe containing scientific symbols and other non-ASCII characters (hence the need for Unicode), and in about 1% of cases its length will exceed 4,000 characters (thus making DT_WSTR 4000 unsuitable). Applying transformations after the XML Source will not be helpful here as the data may already have been truncated due to the DT_WSTR data type's limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is a PITA of SSIS when it is working with standard XML Source.
You have to manually set `DT_NTEXT` data type of Output Column in *Advanced Editor* and take the risk that anyone can hit *Refresh* and ruin your work. Standard XML Source will update Output definition silently, so you have to double check each time you are building project with this package.
Alternative - you can try commercial SSIS XML Source components like [ZappySys](http://zappysys.com/products/ssis-powerpack/ssis-xml-source/) or [BlueSSIS](http://bluessis.com/Index.aspx?PageId=XmlTaskMapComponent). I have no experience with any of these, so cannot recommend.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be the case. After a few days more research I've given up and put a big fat WARNING annotation on the Data Flow sheet calling out the XML Source node for its evil behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I think it is still relevant.
If you'd like to treat all your incoming XML String columns as NVARCHAR(MAX) you can use the following method (after you have saved/refreshed your package and got the default WSTR(255) columns in SSIS):

- Ensure DTSX package is closed in Visual Studio
- Ensure all Destination columns, in the database, is NVARCHAR(MAX)

Open your DTSX package in Notepad++ or any good text editor and:

- Replace ALL
  **dataType="wstr"**
  with
  **dataType="nText"**
- Replace ALL
  **cachedDataType="wstr"**
  with
  **cachedDataType="nText"**
- Replace ALL
  **length="255"**
  with
  **(nothing/empty string)**
- Replace ALL
  **cachedLength="255"**
  with
  **(nothing/empty string)**

Then:

- Open your DTSX from Visual Studio
- Open all Data Flow objects with a Yellow warning sign and just press OK/Enter to fix the yellow warning
- Run your package to test!